# Empty taxonomy pages

Tags: 6, taxonomy-terms

I  am having a taxonomy problem that I can't figure out and my searches haven't helped. Basically, I have created a taxonomy to tag my pages and I can use this field with views etc without any problem. However, when I have created links to those taxonomy terms, the page is coming up as empty (except the term is listed at the top).

If I use /all, then it seems to be working without problem.

So, this works: /taxonomy/term/all

this doesn't: /taxonomy/term/17 (though that term does exist)

this doesn't /taxonomy/term/17/all

In addition, I am using the taxonomy menu module. If I add a new term, it shows up in the menu, but if the counter is enabled, they all show up as "0."

(Drupal 6)

slowly going crazy....

Thanks

Comment: If you are using Views enable the taxonomy view that ships with views and give it a try. Don't forget cleaning the cache.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried both of those things without luck for the individual terms.  For the /all, the view works fine.

Comment: Are your content attached to term 17 correctly? Check it twice. Is your content published?

Comment: They are all published.  I am not sure how to tell if they are attached correctly.  Each item has a keyword that is part of a vocabulary under taxonomy.

Comment: There can be one possibility of not working the taxonomy pages that May be something overriding the taxonomy/term/% pages (it can be view) and you may added any vocabularies conditions or something like that.

Comment: Sorry about the necro. I see somebody's put an active bounty on this so I'll take a stab at it. 
-- To debug, enable the "show the SQL query" option under views/settings. 
-- Manually enter your path into the Query preview field beneath your view. Can you see the tid being correctly passed to the sql query? 
-- Check your arguments / contextual filters - are they parsing the right arg? Check your path wildcards /% - are they parsing the path correctly? Use the bundled taxonomy view for reference.

Comment: Are your Contextual filters set right? It sounds as if the contextual filter for the view is set to the taxonomy term name, instead of the tid.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this question is too broad to have a correct answer. As noted in the comments, there are a few ways that this symptom could occur (i.e. modules that intervene), and tools to diagnose further (e.g. the sql query tool).

For my money, your best bet is to first figure out what code is actually handling the url - you might be able to do that with some debug code, or else by inspecting the menu tables (which are also routing tables in Drupal 6).